# what does "très riping" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The following is an entry of a public school boy's diary. I don't understand what the last phrase "Très riping" means.

> Drove to Canterbury in 3 breaks. Visisted Cathedral, very interesting. Thomas A'Beckett's blood. **Très riping**.
>
> L. P. Hartley, The Go-Between

Does this phrase mean something like "very interesting"? I understand that "très" is a French word meaning "very." But though I checked several dictionaries I could not find an appropriate definition of "riping".

Comment: Probably his mis-spelling of _ripping_, old-fashioned slang for 'very good/exciting'.

Comment: @KateBunting -  Such mis-spellings ('howlers') are practically a trope in the 1950s - I remember the 'Down with Skool', and 'How to be Topp' books that (slightly) pre-dated my schooldays. "History started badly and hav been getting steadily worse".

Comment: 3 errors that I can see - 1.visited 2 Becket 3 ripping.

Answer (score 1):

This "broken english" has resulted in many mispellings, even in just this one sentence.

> mis-spelling of ripping, old-fashioned slang for 'very good/exciting' - @KateBunting

> excellent; splendid; fine [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ripping)

Comment: It isn't 'broken English' as he is a native speaker, just a series of childish spelling errors.